# With C#, how to refer a long Unity property path as a parameter?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to centralise all my Unity GameObject parameters inside one GameObject named gameObjectCompilator. His script is named S_GameObjectCompilator. So, instead of always drag the gameobject inside the inspector, i'll be able to refer to it with C#, without the inspector.

To shorten the path reference, I want to use a variable :
`var GOC = gameObjectCompilator.GetComponent<S_GameObjectCompilator>();`

It worked with this script...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class S_FirstMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gameObjectCompilator;

    public void NewGame()
    {
        var GOC = gameObjectCompilator.GetComponent<S_GameObjectCompilator>();
        GOC.firstMenu.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        GOC.gameUI.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

But, when I want to apply it to my whole script as a parameter, it dosen't works...

```
public class S_FirstMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gameObjectCompilator;
    public string GOC = gameObjectCompilator.GetComponent<S_GameObjectCompilator>();

    public void NewGame()
    {
        GOC.firstMenu.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        GOC.gameUI.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

I know I can't use var outside a local method. So I declare my reference path as a string (which is wrong, I know).

`public string GOC = gameObjectCompilator.GetComponent<S_GameObjectCompilator>();` 
Is there any classes that I can use to be able to apply the GOC variable everywhere in my code ?
Is my vocabulary exact ? I'm a beginner.

Thank you

Comment: well first of all if you look closely you will notice that `gameObjectCompilator.GetComponent<S_GameObjectCompilator>();` doesn't return a `string` but rather a `S_GameObjectCompilator` ... and then Unity will even shout at you and tell you that you can't use `GetComponent` during field initialization (mainly because this in `c#` happens in a `static` environment where `this` is not yet existent!) -> it will even tell you you should initialize the field in `Awake` or `Start`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the component in the `Start` method and store it in a private field.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class S_FirstMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gameObjectCompilator;
    private S_GameObjectCompilator GOC;

    void Start() {
        GOC = gameObjectCompilator.GetComponent<S_GameObjectCompilator>();
    }

    public void NewGame()
    {
        GOC.firstMenu.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        GOC.gameUI.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

#### Further Suggestion:

Also, you could have just declared `gameObjectCompilator` to be of type `S_GameObjectCompilator` in the first place.

And don't be afraid of the long variable names.  Use autocompletion or search and replace or copilot in your IDE to ease the pain of typing.  It's well worth it for improved readability.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class S_FirstMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public S_GameObjectCompilator gameObjectCompilator;

    public void NewGame()
    {
        gameObjectCompilator.firstMenu.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        gameObjectCompilator.gameUI.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: And don't prefix your script class names with `S_`.  `GameObjectCompilator` is a fine class name.  (...not that I know what a _compilator_ is.  DYM "Compiler"?)

Comment: It worked. The second suggestions of @Wyck was great.

I can push it further with 
`public S_GameObjectCompilator GOC;`

I use prefix for Unity. I_ is for images, P_ is for prefabs, etc. So S_ is for scripts. Probably not the right way to organise my things.

I probably mean compiler (as french definition). I want always to refer to the same gameObject, so it stocks all gameObject into one that i named compilator.